# After going back to stock ROM from an unstable custom ROM, my Galaxy S6 keeps freezing

Tags: samsung, custom-roms

I own a Samsung Galaxy S6. I used NNE 5.1 S8 port and it was working well until it got my phone broken somehow.

My phone started acting really strange after 2 months of activity of that new ROM, my phone just started restarting randomly and it got me worried, i thought it's an application problem so i first just factory resetted it. It seemed it was not the problem on an application, so i chose to change my firmware to a stock one. I searched up recently on the newest firmware for S6 and i found out it's: XEF (France) , PDA (AP): G920FXXU6ERC1 and CSC : G920FOXA6ERC1 on 2018-03-22. I Downloaded 4 files: BL,AP,CP,CSC , and i found out about PIT on one of the posts in XDA forum (Filename: SM-G920F-ZEROFLTE_EUR_OPEN.pit).

Before i flashed with Odin, i wiped System, Data, Cache and Dalvik Cache. The firmware worked well but after 1 hour it started doing the same thing but now differently. It happened to me only 1 time that it froze up on an application, but i think that is just an app problem. It isn't actually the app fault, it freezes a while after it boots up. The main problem is that when i lock my screen, i cannot unlock it anymore, it just freezes there until it restarts after a short period of time. After the restart, it just keeps going, restarts, asks for pin, restarts and so on.
I tried removing the sim card and putting it back in, did not work.
I tried Safe mode, still same.

It seems like the phone does not care if it's booted or not. I powered it off charging it, and it restarted itself somehow??

Model of phone: SM-G920F

Current firmware: XEF (G920FXXU6ERC1)

Android version: Nougat (7.0)

Comment: Really? No answers yet ?

Comment: Samsung isn't the best place to start with gaining root access, Some Samsung devices, the S for security on the end of your device name suggests to me that your device is possibly equipped Samsung's security known as (Knox) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Knox

Comment: Didn't you flash the userdata partition when you flashed the stock ROM? That seems like a likely cause of instability; but it's just as likely that this custom ROM just broke the hardware.

Comment: If you have restored to stock and the same, or similar, problems exist it is likely a hardware issue. My guess would be a bad/defective eMMC chip but would need to see a logcat of it which could be difficult if you are not sitting with it connected to a PC actively logging via ADB when the "freeze" occurs.